# SSL error in nginx log

Tags: nginx, log-files

I'm getting this log entry in nginx error log:

```
2016/03/19 09:46:33 [crit] 14355#14355: *7761 SSL_shutdown() failed (SSL: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init) while SSL handshaking, client: 178.63.105.85, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I cannot understand what it means. I have tried to google but without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume you're on Nginx 1.9.x. According to [this thread](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?15,264384,264384) it's a bug in OpenSSL, fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/64193c8218540499984cd63cda41f3cd491f3f59). The thread says "so it should be fixed OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre3-dev". So you probably need to either get the latest version of OpenSSL, or drop back a version of two, because according to [this bug tracker](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/901) it was introduced not long ago.

TLDR: Get the latest OpenSSL.